# Control's Focused property has changed as of Leave handler when using mouse, but not keyboard

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with a TextBox, and need to fire some logic when the textbox has lost focus.

My problem is twofold:

1. The Leave event is firing on every keypress for some reason, meaning the logic is run with every keypress when it should not.
2. When using the Focused property of the Textbox as a double-check, simply exiting out if the property is still set, it now works when the user uses the mouse to leave, but not when the user tabs out.

The Focused property of the TextBox in question is False as of when its Leave event fires when the mouse is used to change focus, but it is still True when the Leave event fires due to a Tab keypress. Seriously?

I need a workaround, because the logic firing on every keystroke is causing a problem for users right now that needs to be fixed post-haste.

Comment: Do you have something running in the TextChanged event?  Obviously, firing the Leave event on every keypress is not normal.

Comment: No, there's nothing attached to TextChanged.

Comment: Are you capturing any other events on a container control or on the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a form with a textbox on it and attached event handler to the leave event of that text box.  I then typed a bunch of stuff into said textbox.  The event was not raised.  I hit tab, the event was raised.  I then clicked back in the textbox, typed some more, and then clicked another control and the event was raised.

I'm just saying that something else is interfering with the textbox.  I would look into that a little more, or post some code demonstrating the problem.